# Another SKSpriteNode is removed when current one is touched

Tags: swift, xcode

I am in developing an application using Xcode and currently I am facing a issue   regarding SKSpriteNodes. When there are more than a single SKSpriteNode and when the node is touched, the touched node is not removed but the other not touched is removed. I have also noticed that when there are multiple nodes on the screen only the latest node coming from the top of the screen is removed whilst others are still moving down, although they are being touched. Can someone help identify why this has occurred and the methods of preventing such mistakes please?

For reference, I am have included the class in which the bug is in.

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit
class GameScene: SKScene {

    private var gameCounter: Int = 0
    private var currentLevel: Int = 0

    private var debug: SKLabelNode?

    private var increasedTouchArea:SKSpriteNode?
    private var generatedNode:SKSpriteNode?

    private var moveAndRemove:SKAction?
    private var moveNode:SKAction?

    // Here we set initial values of counter and level. Debug label is created here as well.
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        print(action(forKey: "counting") == nil)
        gameCounter = 0
        currentLevel = 1
        //backgroundColor = SKColor.gray
        debug = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "ArialMT")
        debug?.fontColor = SKColor.red
        debug?.fontSize = 30.0
        debug?.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY)
        debug?.text = "Counter : [ \(gameCounter) ], Level [ \(currentLevel) ]"
        if let aDebug = debug {
            addChild(aDebug)
        }
    }

    //Method to start a timer. SKAction is used here to track a time passed and to maintain current level
    func startTimer() {
        print("Timer Started...")
        weak var weakSelf: GameScene? = self
        //make a weak reference to scene to avoid retain cycle
        let block = SKAction.run({
            weakSelf?.gameCounter = (weakSelf?.gameCounter ?? 0) + 1
            //Maintaining level
            if (weakSelf?.gameCounter ?? 0) < 5 {
                //level 1
                weakSelf?.currentLevel = 1
            } else if (weakSelf?.gameCounter ?? 0) >= 5 && (weakSelf?.gameCounter ?? 0) < 10 {
                //level 2
                weakSelf?.currentLevel = 2
            } else {
                //level 3
                weakSelf?.currentLevel = 3
            }
            weakSelf?.debug?.text = "Counter : [ \(Int(weakSelf?.gameCounter ?? 0)) ], Level [ \(Int(weakSelf?.currentLevel ?? 0)) ]"
        })
        run(SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.wait(forDuration: 1), block])), withKey: "counting")
    }

    //Method for stopping timer and reseting everything to default state.
    func stopTimer() {
         print("Timer Stopped...")
        if action(forKey: "counting") != nil {
            removeAction(forKey: "counting")
        }
        gameCounter = Int(0.0)
        currentLevel = 1
        debug?.text = "Counter : [ \(gameCounter) ], Level [ \(currentLevel) ]"
    }

    //Get current speed based on time passed (based on counter variable)
    func getCurrentSpeed() -> CGFloat {
        if gameCounter < 30 {
            //level 1
            return 1.0
        } else if gameCounter >= 31 && gameCounter < 49 {
            //level 2
            return 2.0
        } else {
            //level 3
            return 3.0
        }
    }

    //Method which stop generating stones, called in touchesBegan
    func stopGeneratingStones() {
         print("STOPPED GENERATING STONES...")
        if action(forKey: "spawning") != nil {
            removeAction(forKey: "spawning")
        }
    }

    func randomFloatBetween(_ smallNumber: CGFloat, and bigNumber: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        let diff: CGFloat = bigNumber - smallNumber
        return CGFloat(arc4random() % (UInt32(RAND_MAX) + 1)) / CGFloat(RAND_MAX) * diff + smallNumber
    }

    //Method for generating stones, you run this method when you want to start spawning nodes (eg. didMoveToView or when some button is clicked)
    func generateStones() {
         print("Generating Stones...")
        let delay = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 1, withRange: 0.5) //Change forDuration: delay decreases as game progresses.
        //randomizing delay time
        weak var weakSelf: GameScene? = self
        //make a weak reference to scene to avoid retain cycle
        let block = SKAction.run({
            let stone: SKSpriteNode? = weakSelf?.spawnNodes(withSpeed: weakSelf?.getCurrentSpeed() ?? 0.0)
            stone?.zPosition = 20
            if let aStone = stone {
                weakSelf?.addChild(aStone)
            }
        })
        run(SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.sequence([delay, block])), withKey: "spawning")
    }

    func spawnNodes(withSpeed stoneSpeed: CGFloat) -> SKSpriteNode? {
        let nodeSize = CGSize(width: 60, height: 60) //size of shape.
        let initalNodePosition = CGPoint(x: randomFloatBetween(0.0, and: (self.view?.bounds.size.width)!) - 110, y: frame.maxY)
        generatedNode = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.green, size: nodeSize)
        generatedNode?.position = initalNodePosition 
        moveNode = SKAction.moveBy(x: 0, y: self.view!.scene!.frame.minY + self.view!.scene!.frame.minY , duration: 5.25)
        generatedNode?.isUserInteractionEnabled = false //Allows users to touch shape.
        increasedTouchArea = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.clear, size: CGSize(width: nodeSize.width * 1.35, height: nodeSize.height * 1.35))
        increasedTouchArea?.name = "generatedNode"
        increasedTouchArea?.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        generatedNode?.addChild(increasedTouchArea!)
        moveNode?.speed = stoneSpeed
        moveAndRemove = SKAction.sequence([moveNode!, SKAction.removeFromParent()])
        generatedNode?.run(moveAndRemove!, withKey: "moving")
        generatedNode?.name = "generatedNode"
        return generatedNode
    }

    func deleteNode(){
        moveAndRemove = SKAction.sequence([SKAction.removeFromParent()])
        generatedNode?.run(moveAndRemove!, withKey: "moving")
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent? {
        for touch in touches {
            let locationTocuhed = touch.location(in: self)
            let touchedNode : SKNode = self.atPoint(locationTocuhed)
            if touchedNode.name == generatedNode?.name {
                print("Node touched")
                deleteNode()
            }
        }
        if action(forKey: "counting") == nil {
            print("Game started...")
            startTimer()
            generateStones()
        } else {
            print("Game paused...")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method deleteNode() runs the deletion animation on the node pointed to by **generatedNode**, not the node last touched:

```
func deleteNode(){
    moveAndRemove = SKAction.sequence([SKAction.removeFromParent()])
    generatedNode?.run(moveAndRemove!, withKey: "moving")
}
```

If you want to delete the node last touched, pass a reference to this node to the method deleteNode and then run your deletion animation in that, not generatedNode.

Comment: Yeah sure, what you say definitely makes sense on the method is not working as intended. Your answer definitely sounds promising, however as I am new to Swift coming from a Java background I do not know how to implement weak reference types.

Comment: You cannot make a Swift method parameter weak if that is what you mean. However you should not need to? Pass the node to be deleted to your method deleteNode, it will be 'retained' by that parameter only for the duration of the call, then it will be retained by the action but once the action has run it should be released as normal (once generatedNode no longer points to it - what is that for by the way? SKScene will retain all added nodes itself so you do not need to retain your own references to them once added).

Comment: By the way you do not need the SKAction in deleteNode, you can call removeFromParent directly, but I assume you intend to add animation to the action later?

Comment: Yeah I plan to add animations later during the development phase. Sure I understand that I need to pass the touched node as a parameter down to the 'deleteNode' method. I have added 'func deleteNode(referenceNode: SKNode)' to my method and 'deleteNode(referenceNode: SKNode)' where the touches began but I am shown an error Cannot convert value of type **'SKNode.Type' to expected argument type 'SKNode'**

Comment: Yes, don't call the method with the type, call it with the var :o) - deleteNode(referencedNode:touchedNode)

Comment: Thank you, I have implemented what you have said and it has worked. Now I understand on why it initially did not work and I am aware of the solution to the problem. I really appreciate the support and advices!